# How to ignore base href when using location.href="#_ElementId_"?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

If a webpage has a base href, is there anyway to ignore it when we're using #*ElementId*, without refreshing the page?

Here's some code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://www.google.com/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      Test
    </div>
    <button onclick="location.href='#test'">Back to Test</button>
    <a href="#test">Back to Test!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on either the button or the link, I want the browser to bring the page to div#test. Without the base href tag, everything works - However, with the base-href tag, I can't do it without the help of Javascript. Is there a way to do it in a more "natural" way?

Below's a workaround that I have at the moment...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://www.google.com/" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function goToElement(elementId) {
        var baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
        var existingBaseHref = baseTag.href;
        baseTag.href = "";
        location.href = "#" + elementId;
        baseTag.href = existingBaseHref;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      Test
    </div>
    <button onclick="goToElement('test')">Back to Test</button>
    <a onclick="goToElement('test')">Back to Test!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have the base href? And why not just set location.hash to the elementId ?

Comment: @mplungjan - Base-href: Historic code-base reasons, unfortunately. :( On location.hash - Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make anchor links refer to the current page when using <base>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108836/make-anchor-links-refer-to-the-current-page-when-using-base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just have to output the full absolute URL in your link's href attribute.

For example, you could do something like this in ASP.NET (using the [AntiXss library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=F4CD231B-7E06-445B-BEC7-343E5884E651)):

```
<a href="<%= AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) %>#test">
    Link text...
</a>
```

Or something like this in PHP:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1'); ?>#test">
    Link text...
</a>
```

Comment: Would this cause the page to re-load? (Thanks for answering, BTW.) In my case, I can't let the page reload (Adding this to the question.)

Comment: No, it shouldn't cause the page to reload (I'd be suprised if it did)

Comment: Works! Thanks for the help. I guess I need to figure out how to determine the absolute URL now. Haa.

Answer (score 2):

This will scroll to the element with id="test" and the return false will make it stay on the page.

`<a href="#test" onclick="document.getElementById('test').scrollIntoView(); return false">Go to div with id=test</a>`

It does not seem to be possible to do what you want without either using script or addIng the full path to the href on the server

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using . This was my solution that worked on interior pages, for example www.mozilla.org/about

```
<div>
  <a href="/about#target"></a>
  <p>Content...</p>
  <div id="target">
    Target Div
  </div>
</div>
```