# Html base tag breaks the # reference

Tags: angularjs, html, radix, meanjs

I am creating an HTML5 application with angular. To work I need to add the base URL in the html header.

```
<base href="/">
```

Then when I click en the footnote, it do not redirect to the correct url.

```
http://micd.herokuapp.com/#fnref2:1
```

Instead of

```
http://micd.herokuapp.com/articles/556acc58cbf0d10b000be0c8#fnref2:1
```

I wonder if you have any clues to make the to fix this.

Thanks !

Comment: What happens if you set `/articles/556acc58cbf0d10b000be0c8` as your `<base href="/articles/556acc58cbf0d10b000be0c8">`?...

Comment: It breaks the application because the requests are not more correctly forwarded ...

Comment: Makes sense. It was worth a try though.

Comment: Somewhat related, though i don't like any of these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108836/make-anchor-links-refer-to-the-current-page-when-using-base

Comment: Thanks! I think I will find a way to do it !

Comment: Thanks @KevinB, I found a solution in the thread!

Comment: please don't post solutions in your question, that's what answers are for. (you can see the revision history by [clicking here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30629915/revisions))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using markdown-it, so I edited rules by adding the pathname to every links.

```
var md = window.markdownit()
    .use(window.markdownitFootnote);

md.renderer.rules.footnote_ref = function (tokens, idx) {
  var n = Number(tokens[idx].meta.id + 1).toString();
  var id = 'fnref' + n;
  var uri = window.location.pathname;
  if (tokens[idx].meta.subId > 0) {
    id += ':' + tokens[idx].meta.subId;
  }
  return '<sup class="footnote-ref"><a href="' + uri + '#fn' + n + '" id="' + id + '">[' + n + ']</a></sup>';
};

md.renderer.rules.footnote_anchor = function(tokens, idx) {
  var n = Number(tokens[idx].meta.id + 1).toString();
  var id = 'fnref' + n;
  var uri = window.location.pathname;
  if (tokens[idx].meta.subId > 0) {
    id += ':' + tokens[idx].meta.subId;
  }
  return ' <a href="' + uri + '#' + id + '" class="footnote-backref">\u21a9</a>'; /* ↩ */
};
```

Non specific solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $('a').each(function () {
       var link = $(this).attr('href');
       if (link.substr(0,1) == "#") {
           $(this).attr('href', pathname + link);
       }
    });
}
```